# Sequence in which mysql execute queries

Tags: mysql

If I have three queries line by line then what is the sequence in which mysql executes queries?
For example:
If i am checking user's distance like whether he is within the range of 1 mile or not and in second condition is he in range of 2 miles or not ..then first if user is in 1 mile then i am updating records and sending notification.but then he moved to 2 mile range so again i am updating records and sending notifications then can my second condition executes before first condition?

Answer (score 0):

They are executed in sequential order, but only if they are all executed from within the *same* connection!

If you have multiple connections, the order depends on the *isolation level*. Have a look at the [set Transaction syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html) for more information.